# Cannot require properly in PHP

Tags: php, path, require

I've the datastructure of the first image.

The code below is from Class.CIBootstrap.php

And as you can see, on the 4th line i do:

```
require 'Class.CIAjaxHandler.php';
```

and that works fine. Now, if it's not an ajax I want to load the proper controller...

This does NOT work. As you can see from the structure CIAjaxHandler is in the same folder as the CIBootstrap, but the CILoginController that I try to access isnt, but why cant I access it via

`require '../controllers/Class.CILoginController.php'` ?

[image: structur]
[image: code]

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Warning: require(../controllers/Class.CILoginController.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\chapAptana\classes\misc\Class.CIBootstrap.php on line 39

Comment: Have you tried set_include_path() before the require?

Comment: Post the code will you? It should be easier than screenshooting your desktop.

Comment: You may have a permissions issue.  What are the permissions on the `controllers` folder?

Comment: If you use php 5.3 `require __DIR__ . '/../controllers/controller.php';`

Comment: I cannot find any difference in the permissions.. I run Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be a good idea define absolute path. Because:

- Files/Folders could change location in the future
- Prevent issues like your question (the parent file could not be the same for different call)
- If you look the code, you know where you should find the files

So, simply include a constant file where you can generate cascade of path like so:

```
define('PATH_ROOT'    ,__DIR__.'/');
define('PATH_CLASSES' , PATH_ROOT.'classes/');
// ...
```

and in your scripts

```
require_once PATH_CLASSES.'controller/Class.CIAjaxHandler.php';
```

In this case you are absolute sure what you include, and WHERE is the file that you want include.

Suppose you've this structure:

**/root.php**

```
<?php echo "Hello World";
```

**/index.php**

```
 <?php 
 include 'path1/path1.php';
```

**/path1/path1.php**

```
<?php 
include '../root.php';
```

In this case if you call `/path1/path1.php` the script works, because include root.php in parent folder and it's ok.
But if you call `/index.php` it does not works, because the inclusion file is already relative to parent folder.

So, if in your software you plan to call different files in different locations, use constants COULD be one solution.

Another solution could be set an [include path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) or to specify always an absolute path with `__DIR__` at start of relative path.

Comment: i never had any problem with `../` so why absolute path is good idea ? could you specify ?

Comment: @NullPointer I given 3 points... and I've not given an "absolute" rule. Sometimes it could be a good idea.

Comment: @NullPointer if you include a filel that include another file, from different other files and different locations, the `../` can give some problems

Comment: This is what I will stick to from now on.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, use path relative to current file:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../controller/Class.CILoginController.php';
```

or in php 5.3+:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../controller/Class.CILoginController.php';
```

Your code works when there is a request with `$_GET['page'] == 'ajax'`, but to what file is this request issued most probably somewhere in `misc` folder)? But when `$_GET['page'] !== 'ajax'` it may be called by other script (like `index.php` outside `misc` dir) so current working directory for php process may differ.

Comment: But the thing is, everything is called from index.php from the beginning, both ajax and regular

Comment: @DavidEverlöf I have the same setup - a .htaccess file routes everything through index.php, then everything goes through __autoload(). I set the set_include_path() WITHIN my __autoload() function, and it works great :)

Comment: And where is this index.php located in your tree? are you using `chdir` anywhere in your code?

Comment: The index.php is located in a another place, somewhere in the htdocs. I'm not using chdir, the parent of classes is "chapAptana", htdocs lies in the same folder as chapAptana, and index.php is located in htdocs/chap/index.php

Comment: @Jimbo might look intho that, never used autoload(), or Ill just stick to absolute paths

Comment: Thanks for the efforts guys

Comment: so it looks like that `misc` is in your include path, although it's convenient  I wouldn't recommend it, better define folders where you have classes and use autoloader for it, just like @chumkiu suggested.